# DataSource class can not resolve symbol

Tags: java, sql, package

When I am compiling the below java file I am getting error for DataSource class. It is not  showing any error in the import statement. Please help me.

Sample code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
public class DBConnectionManager
{
private Hashtable pools;
public synchronized Connection getConnection(String s)
{
    try
    {
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource)pools.get(s);
        Object obj = null;
        if(datasource != null)
        {
            Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
            return connection;
        } else
        {
            InitialContext initialcontext = new InitialContext();
            Object obj1 = initialcontext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/" + s);
            DataSource datasource1 = (DataSource)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj1, javax.sql.DataSource.class);
            pools.put(s, datasource1);
            Connection connection1 = datasource1.getConnection();
            return connection1;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlexception)
    {
        log(sqlexception, "SQL In getConnection for pool " + s);
    }
    catch(NamingException namingexception)
    {
        log(namingexception, "Naming In getConnection for pool " + s);
    }
    return null;
}    
}
```

Error is

DBConnectionManager.java:56: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class DataSource
location: class DBConnectionManager
            DataSource datasource = (DataSource)pools.get(s);
            ^
DBConnectionManager.java:56: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class DataSource
location: class DBConnectionManager
            DataSource datasource = (DataSource)pools.get(s);
                                     ^
DBConnectionManager.java:66: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class DataSource
location: class DBConnectionManager
                DataSource datasource1 = (DataSource)PortableRemoteObject.narrow
(obj1, javax.sql.DataSource.class);
                ^
DBConnectionManager.java:66: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class DataSource
location: class DBConnectionManager
                DataSource datasource1 = (DataSource)PortableRemoteObject.narrow
(obj1, javax.sql.DataSource.class);

4 errors

Answer (score 0):

Post the stack trace.  It'll be more helpful than your question.

I don't see where pools is declared or initialized anywhere.

Is there a JAR in your CLASSPATH that has `javax.sql.DataSource` in it?  If not, you'll need one.

Answer (score -1):

## 1 I'm assuming your first import line is a typo

Second, try changing this:

```
DataSource datasource = (DataSource)pools.get(s);
```

to

```
DataSource datasource = (DataSource)(pools.get(s));
```

I suspect you are casting pools to a DataSource and then trying to call the "get" method which probably doesn't exist.  What I think you want to do is cast the result of the "get" method to a DataSource.